# Does new activity need content and activity xml?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-activity, android-studio

Since the latest changes, the main activity has an activity_main.xml and a content_main.xml.

I'm creating a new activity now in the same project but no matter how I create it, I can't get Android Studio to create both xml files for the new activity. This means that I can't remove the toolbar unless I do so programmatically. That's fine by me.

Ultimately, I'm just wondering if I should create both xml files for the second activity.... like:

activity_notmain.xml
content_notmain.xml

or should I just create the one layout file and remove the toolbar programmatically?

Comment: If you dont want the toolbar, just remove that from the layout file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just right click on res>layout and go to new>activity>blank activity then enter name for activity and layout file it will automatically create both activity and content xml file

Comment: That did it. I was using Gallery. Thanks!